# Popup picker in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I need to implement a picker like in this image. How can I do this? I'm using Xamarin.iOS but I can use an answer with native code and translate it myself.

[image: Picker]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a PickerView to TextField's `InputView` property and assign a Toolbar to `InputAccessoryView`, like this:

```
UIToolbar toolBar = new UIToolbar(new CGRect(0, 0, 320, 44));
UIBarButtonItem flexibleSpaceLeft = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace,null,null);
UIBarButtonItem doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem("OK",UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done,this, new ObjCRuntime.Selector("DoneAction"));
UIBarButtonItem[] list = new UIBarButtonItem[] { flexibleSpaceLeft, doneButton };
toolBar.SetItems(list, false);

UIPickerView pickerView = new UIPickerView(new CGRect(0, 44, 320, 216));
pickerView.DataSource = new MyUIPickerViewDataSource();
pickerView.Delegate = new MyUIPickerViewDelegate();
pickerView.ShowSelectionIndicator = true;

textField.InputAccessoryView = toolBar;
textField.InputView = pickerView;
```

After you implement your `DataSource` and `Delegate` of the pickerview, it can work like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

use an [ActionSheet](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/alertcontroller/#ActionSheet_Alert)

```
actionSheetButton.TouchUpInside += ((sender, e) => {

            // Create a new Alert Controller
            UIAlertController actionSheetAlert = UIAlertController.Create("Action Sheet", "Select an item from below", UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);

            // Add Actions
            actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Item One",UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => Console.WriteLine ("Item One pressed.")));

            actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Item Two",UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => Console.WriteLine ("Item Two pressed.")));

            actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Item Three",UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => Console.WriteLine ("Item Three pressed.")));

            actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel",UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, (action) => Console.WriteLine ("Cancel button pressed.")));

            // Required for iPad - You must specify a source for the Action Sheet since it is
            // displayed as a popover
            UIPopoverPresentationController presentationPopover = actionSheetAlert.PopoverPresentationController;
            if (presentationPopover!=null) {
                presentationPopover.SourceView = this.View;
                presentationPopover.PermittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up;
            }

            // Display the alert
            this.PresentViewController(actionSheetAlert,true,null);
        });
```

Comment: That's similar, but not the same "spinner" control as in the photo. I'm pretty sure it's a native control?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kevin Li for the answer, just wanted to give a simplified version in case anyone needs this. Not exactly what was originally asked for, but does the job.

```
        var pickerView = new UIPickerView();
        var sports = new string[] { "baseball", "basketball", "wiener dog" };
        var model = new PickerModel(sports);

        model.PickerChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            txtSport.Text = sports[e.SelectedValue];
        };

        pickerView.Model = model;
        pickerView.ShowSelectionIndicator = true;

        // setting picker view to your textfield
        txtSport.InputView = pickerView;
```